# Some users unable to pass a test

Tags: moodle

We have an installation of Moodle with several courses and users.
Recently we have reported that at least one user cannot pass an exam. He retried several times and always obtains 0 score with message:

> Results Your Score: 0% (0 points)

What is almost impossible because the quiz has 25 questions and many of them are True/False type
I tried to change the Auto Save Delay option to 30 seconds to save the questions while are responded but it does not work.

[image]Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for programmers. Your question might have a better chance of receiving an answer in another venue. Perhaps a Moodle-specific forum.

Comment: Yeah, this is a configuration issue. The quiz probably has zero grades set up. Try asking the question at https://moodle.org/mod/forum/view.php?f=32 or read the quiz documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Quiz_activity